# OpenCV - KMeans2 resulting in many empty clusters

Tags: python, opencv, k-means

I'm using OpenCV's (Python) kmeans2 function to cluster a set of SURF features extracted from a set of images.

```
cv.KMeans2(mat,CLUSTER_COUNT,labels,(cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,100,1.0),centers = cent)
```

I'm running it on a set of around 50,000 features, setting my CLUSTER_COUNT to 2000. However I only get 253 clusters which are non-empty. The remaining clusters have no features assigned to them.

I'm not sure what OpenCV's implementation of K-Means looks like, but I would have thought that when there is an empty cluster, the centre is reassigned or something?

Is there something wrong with the way I am calling it or is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try [cv2.kmeans](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html?highlight=kmeans2#cv2.kmeans) instead which is easier to understand. If the problem remains please let us know.

Comment: I actually figured it out yesterday and that was precisely the problem. cv.KMeans2 is a legacy version which does not deal with empty clusters. I looked through the source and the new function does the following for an empty cluster:
1. Find the largest cluster
2. Select the furthest point from the cluster centre
3. Set that point as a the new centre (to replace the empty one)

So no empty clusters!